# Webstorm does not recognize my ngrx/effect

Tags: angular, ngrx-effects

This effect functions correctly, but webstorm seems to be unable to recognize it.

```
  sendUserName$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(sendUserName),
      map((action) => {
        return this.usernameService.SearchUserName(action.username).pipe(
          map((result) => of(sendUserNameSuccess({found: result.found}))),
          catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => of(sendUserNameFail({error: error.message})))
        );
      })
    ));
```

The error message is:

```
Argument type () => Observable<Observable<({error: string} & TypedAction<"[app] Send user name failed">) | Observable<{found: boolean} & TypedAction<"[app] Send user name success">>>> is not assignable to parameter type () => (EffectResult<ObservableType<DispatchType<EffectConfig>, OT>> & ConditionallyDisallowActionCreator<DispatchType<EffectConfig>, EffectResult<ObservableType<DispatchType<EffectConfig>, OT>>>)
```

Does anyone know what this means and how to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: If you run `npm start`, does it give you the same error? Also, if you load the project in VS Code, does it give the same error?

Comment: Hi @AliF50, yes it does

Comment: Try changing your first `map` to a `switchMap`.

Comment: Hi @user15116257, were you able to resolve this ?

Comment: @AliF50 I did attempt this, but this did not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, removing node_modules and reinstalling all node packages resolved it for me.

Comment: This actually solved it for me as well for some reason. 
Maybe because I ran npm install from within webstorm instead of in WSL. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The solution for us was enabling the 'TypeScript language service' in the Intellij properties.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, no node interpreter was set for Typescript. After I selected an interpreter, the error disappeared.
[image]